# Why doesn't this simple Highcarts JS Fiddle example reset the XAxis with SetCategories call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The title of the question says it all. I have this fiddle [SetCateforiesFiddleExample](http://jsfiddle.net/5tzjoq3h/)

What I want to do is to change the categories from months to numbers as a simple example to apply to my real application. Can someone assit me as to why this fiddle doesn't properly set the categories to numbers?

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});


// the button action
$('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.xAxis[0].remove(false);
    chart.addAxis({
          lineWidth: 2,
          lineColor: '#08F'},
          true,false);
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'], false);
    chart.redraw();
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing your axis, adding new axis and set its categories, I would rather update axis with new categories and options using Axis.update():

```
    chart.xAxis[0].update({
    lineWidth: 2,
    lineColor: '#08F',
    categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
  },
  true, false);
```

Here you can see an example how it can work; http://jsfiddle.net/5tzjoq3h/17/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly you want to change xAxis categories from months to numbers , for this you need simply just put them when you call highcharts method

```
 xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    }
```

instead of this you can write simply

```
     xAxis: {
            categories: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']
}
```

[here is the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5tzjoq3h/2/)

Comment: The point is that I'm trying to dynamically change them. The graph renders as months but when I push the button they should change to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Fires when a series is added to the chart after load time, using the addSeries method. One parameter, event, is passed to the function.  Through event.options you can access the series options that was passed to the addSeries method. Returning false prevents the series from being added. so you have not write false after `chart.xAxis[0].setCategories([...], false);` instead of this you have to write `chart.xAxis[0].setCategories([...], true);`
also you needed to write proper statement chain to invoke redraw function like this `chart.events.redraw();`
[here is the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5tzjoq3h/16/)